# How to require the values of an object's properties to contain certain substrings?

Tags: typescript

I am experimenting with ideas for an API config system, and would like some help on typing a config object.

Note: In terms of the API, this is a resources/endpoints config, with each resource/endpoint having a specified path which must contain certain parameters. I will talk more in terms of TypeScript, to simplify terminology and avoid confusion.

The basic problem is that I have a config object, where each of the properties has a nested property that must contain certain substrings.
I have this schema object, which defines what substrings the nested property must contain (the substrings specified in this object are each wrapped in curly braces to create the actual substring):

```
const pathsSchema = {
  foo: {
    params: ["id"], // substring would be `{id}`
  },
} as const;
```

(I generate a type from this object. I can't remember why I decided it needs to be an object instead of just a type. If they want to, answerers can ignore it and just use a type directly.)

The corresponding config object for this schema would be something like the following:

```
const config = {
  foo: {
    path: "foo?id={id}",
  },
};
```

---

With a single substring, it is simple, as I can just type it with the following:

```
Path<param extends string> = `${string}{${param}}${string}`

type Paths<schema = typeof pathsSchema> = {
  [name in keyof schema]: {
    path: Path<schema[name]["param"]>
  };
};
```

However, a similar approach with multiple substrings would require generating every possible permutation, which is obviously not a good idea.
Update: This is moot! See update at bottom of question.

So currently I have this generic type that resolves to `true` if a string contains the required substrings:

```
type CheckPath<path extends string, params extends string[]> =
  // A. If there is a first param, get it.
  params extends [infer param extends string, ...infer rest extends string[]]
    ? path extends `${string}{${param}}${string}` // B. If path contains param...
      ? CheckPath<path, rest> // B. ...check next param...
      : false // B. ...else, path is invalid.
    : true; // A. There are no more params, so path is valid.
```

I then have the following framework. The `defineConfig` helper is a pattern used to provide typing in a separate, "user"-provided config file; e.g. `vite.config.ts` for Vite.

```
const defineConfig = (config: Paths) => config;

const config = defineConfig({
  foo: {
    path: "foo?id={id}",
  },
});
```

Is there some way I can require that the object passed to `defineConfig` passes checking with `CheckPath`?
I do not like these kind of "validation" types, but I don't know if there's another way.
Update: This is moot: template literal types can be intersected! Yay TypeScript! (Thanks to Alex Wayne for pointing this out.)
So now my question boils down to: **how do I go from this schema with a map of names-to-string-arrays to a map of names-to-intersections-of-template-literal-types?**

Comment: can you go into more detail? When should a `config` be valid and when not? How do you tell `defineConfig` about the existence of `pathsSchema`?

Comment: The config object should be valid when the `path` subproperty of each property has the required substrings as defined in the schema object.

Comment: As to the `pathsSchema`, I was passing its type as a type param to the `Paths` type, as seen in the single substring example at the bottom of my question.

Comment: would [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKR0Zm) fit your needs? If so, I would write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found its usually best to avoid validation types that return `true` in favor of a type that simply defines the data you want.

---

One cool thing is that you can intersect string template types, and both must apply.

```
type AB = `${string}a${string}` & `${string}b${string}`
const str1: AB = `__a_b__` // fine
const str2: AB = `b_a123` // fine
const str3: AB = `a123` // error, no `b`
```

So this gives a place to start.

---

Next let's make utility type to turn a `string[]` of param names into this intersection of strings.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type Path<Params extends string[]> = UnionToIntersection<
    {
        [K in keyof Params & number]: `${string}{${Params[K]}}${string}`
    }[number]
>

type TestAB = Path<['a', 'b']>
//   ^? `${string}a${string}` & `${string}b${string}`

const pathGood: Path<['id']> = 'path?id={id}' // fine
const pathGood2: Path<['id', 'name']> = 'path?myname={name}&id={id}' // fine
const pathBad: Path<['id']> = 'asd?bad={bad}' // error
```

The `Path` type here takes a tuple of params and maps over them creating the string type for each param. We then index that by `number` to turn that object into a union of its values. And lastly we use the fantastic `UnionToIntersection` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/62076) to combine them all into the intersection type we need.

---

That's one path, but to do the whole object we need more types.

```
type Paths<
    Config extends { [name: string]: { params: string[] } }
> = {
    [K in keyof Config]: {
        path: Path<Config[K]['params']>
    }
}
```

This type maps over a config type and finds the keys and corresponding param types the final paths need to make.

With that we can make a schema type:

```
type MyPathsSchema = {
  foo: { params: ["id"] },
  bar: { params: ["id", 'name'] },
}
```

And use it in a function:

```
function defineConfig<
    MyPaths extends Paths<MyPathsSchema>
>(paths: MyPaths) {
  //...
}
```

And test it out:

```
defineConfig({
    foo: { path: 'foo?id={id}' },
    bar: { path: 'foo?name={name}&id={id}' }
}) // fine

defineConfig({
    foo: { path: 'foo?id={id}' },
    bar: { path: 'foo?name={name}' }
}) // Type '"foo?name={name}"' is not assignable to type
   //      '`${string}{id}${string}` & `${string}{name}${string}`'.
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ts=4.8.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oAoKKAChiggA8c4ATfKAEM4IKAH5WAawBcsAJS0qANyQJeUWXAhK8cjtwh8BLFjKgI4AMzxQMC5at56JGDVC07cDBqEhQACoLAABbkgbiCALYCXDz8UPjAuBYA5gDaALo09PBk6Fg4BMSkKORMzFAA3uUVFWkA0uZwUJIQIEiWAYIR0VAAZO4ArpEARngZsgAGACSViclwKQC+lbPhUfgNGUtLs-OpS5M1UEtpcMNjuBkMVN6+0KgQiQCCdF0h5GkA5IJfADRQL4jL5ZBgAejBFQAemJvEQUIkoGAgsEAOJIJC8WSBD7fNQg7KA5EhMRqWiVNRLL4MeFwRHEtEY3gAJmxKM+X3xAK+cCiEAJby+DLEkRAvMiEHJ4ogSz6ZIpvCpNIRwCRKIAQoIse9QnjeAL6D98LwxCMteSzYrqd4fOBoDjgvgyrUAMIoSwIFL6OICSpQM582T7RYTKpqnr4INJVKZE4nG5vaq1BpNFptDpQN1WT2hpO1CoMtkfLMe9L1DLfZERgnHJYMOu2vwAWRADvwAGUiMEIJFBInypYMbI-VWNrI0gAiNQTjInP7lM24Yfhsf+qe8Cfc6Uguf17yWQZwEhkKC8CAerQlz3OiottvewzxNvkO8ojtdnuCW5UFgMyNQV8QnwPRKgbM8LwgK8UhYPNmEHJBl0LQF4NJXhyUpL5d1qRdEJRWQvhQ6UpT5WV5Qw+Mlj0CEoAg7xwIsSD3U9GDjng3CQnwlCyKtLCKhwsMkIIjExCIyppSpCiqMhVA7UBCdCL5YiJSWCdMIQAQ4CQVVBHwfBPV5EYABtoGAJAoHuGpqPzL4ZjmaNFhWSk9ns5ZJn6KBbODZYxJI5yFlcr4ADogA)

Comment: Solid. Didn't know you could intersect template literal types like that! There should be no need for `keyof Params & number`, though.

Comment: Neither did I until this question! Tried it and it worked. <3 Typescript.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! Fantastic answer, as usual. I guessed TypeScript must have some method for the template literal side of it, but I didn't think of simply trying to intersect them. I tried it out quickly and it appears to work. I'll try it out properly after the weekend and see what happens. :)